# Tomcat 8.5 cat Unit tomcat.service not found

Tags: java, tomcat8

I cannot run tomcat service from regular user though I can run it manually using scripts in the tomcat directory.
My PC also does not have service script for tomcat int the directory /etc/init.d/tomcat. How can I add service script?